# Obtaining public key from certificate

Tags: java, cryptography

I'm trying to obtain the public key of a Certificate using the method:

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("PathToCertificate");
CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)f.generateCertificate(fin);
PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();
```

but I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl cannot be cast to codec.x509.X509Certificate
        at sergas_testcertificates.Main.main(Main.java:54)
```

Does anyone know what this error is about?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What type of key is it?  RSA?  I've seen similar messages before with unsupported keys.

Comment: The full stack trace could help identify the problem.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I added the full stack trace to the ioriginal post.

Comment: Are you sure the code provided is where the error is? I would expect to see a call to KeyFactory.generatePublic() based on the stacktrace

Comment: @Sean Sorry you're right! I messed out with the versions! Please see the new error above in the edited post.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have the wrong class imported for `X509Certificate`.

You are likely looking for `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` not `codec.x509.X509Certificate`.

Comment: That's right! I import now java.security.cert.X509Certificate and it's working OK. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @javi: If this was the solution, mark it as "best answer", using the checkmark icon beside the answer.

Answer (score 10):

```
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)f.generateCertificate(fin);
PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();
```

since you are only pulling the public key, you can use the certificate class. The factory class will decide what type of a certificate to return.

```
Certificate certificate = f.generateCertificate(fin);
PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();
```

If you need to cast this for antoher reason, check your imports and change it, X509Certificate should be coming from javax.security.cert