# Verifying RSA SHA256 signature fails getting private key from certificate

Tags: java, cryptography, certificate, rsa, private-key

I'm trying to verify a data string and its RSA-SHA256 signature received from a webservice and I'm completely stuck loading the private/public key from the certificate.

I have the following code to retrieve info from the cer file, I think that is in a DER format because it's not in the typical base64 encoded:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path1);
CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(in);
System.out.println(cert.toString());
```

It outputs the whole info of the certificate:

```
Version: V3
Subject: EMAILADDRESS=...
...
Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
...
```

but if a try to load and retrieve the private key with the following code:

```
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");        
X509EncodedKeySpec bobPubKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey bobPubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(bobPubKeySpec);
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
sig.initVerify(bobPubKey);
sig.update(data_received);
sig.verify(signature_received);
```

I get the following exception

```
 java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
```

in the keyFactory.generatePublic method. Same result if a change it to generatePrivate.

Comment: Firstly, a private key and public are two very different things. You verify with a public key. The certificate contains a public key. There is no private key involved in the verification piece. Secondly, since you have figured out how to read in the certificate just call [`getPublicKey()` on the X509Certificate object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358555/obtaining-public-key-from-certificate).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks James, following your advise I made it with the following:

```
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\" + certificateName);
        CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(in);
        PublicKey pubKey = cert.getPublicKey();


        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
        sig.initVerify(pubKey);
        sig.update(xmlContent);

        return sig.verify(headerSignature);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [`initVerify` that simply takes a certificate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html#initVerify(java.security.cert.Certificate)). Internaly it will of course just get the public key, but there is generally no reason for *you* to do so.