# Spring boot unresolved reference oauth2 resource server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

I asked a question not long ago to know [how to validate jwt token using spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67419689/how-to-validate-tokens-received-from-authorization-server) and copied the dependencies on the sample [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/oauth2/resource-server/static) but updated them for the latest ones.

This is my build.gradle :

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.32'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring' version '1.4.32'
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa" version "1.4.32"
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-jpa'

group = 'com.backend-project'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    def appInsightsVersion = '2.6.2'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:6.2.1.jre8'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.199'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core'
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api'
    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-web', version: appInsightsVersion
    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'applicationinsights-logging-logback', version: appInsightsVersion
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.4.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.4.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:2.4.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:5.3.9.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:5.3.9.RELEASE'

    compile 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.11.2'
    runtime 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.11.2',
            'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.11.2'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.10'
    implementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on', version: '1.68'


}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict']
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjsr305=strict']
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}


task copyWebConfig(type: Copy) {
    from("$rootDir/src/main/templates") {
        include 'web.config'
    }
    into "$buildDir/libs"
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [VERSION: project.version])
    inputs.property("VERSION", project.version)
    filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [PACKAGE_NAME: project.name])
    inputs.property("PACKAGE_NAME", project.name)

}

task copyLogBack(type: Copy) {
    from("$rootDir") {
        include 'logback-spring.xml'
    }
    into "$buildDir/libs"
}

assemble.dependsOn(copyWebConfig)
assemble.dependsOn(copyLogBack)
```

this is my web security implementation :

```kotlin
package com.renaulttrucks.transfertprotocolbackend.security.config

import com.renaulttrucks.transfertprotocolbackend.api.config.Router
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey

@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Value("\${security.enabled}")
    val securityEnabled : Boolean? = false

    @Value("\${jwt.key-path}")
    var keyPath: String? = null

    var publicKey: RSAPublicKey? = null

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {

        if(!securityEnabled!!) {
            http.httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
        } else {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/companies/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(Router.API_PATH + "/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .anonymous()
                .and()
                .securityContext()
                .and()
                .headers().disable()
                .rememberMe().disable()
                .requestCache().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .x509().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                    .jwt(jwt -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder()))
                )
        }
    }

    @Bean
    fun jwtDecoder(): JwtDecoder? {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(getPublicKeyFromString()).build()
    }

    fun getPublicKeyFromString(): RSAPublicKey? {
        if (this.publicKey != null) {
            return this.publicKey
        }
        val fin = FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile(keyPath!!))
        val f: CertificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509")
        val certificate: X509Certificate = f.generateCertificate(fin) as X509Certificate
        publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey() as RSAPublicKey?
        return publicKey
    }

}
```

The error happens here : [image]

It gives me the following errors which I don't understand why I'm getting since I'm following the documentation :
[image]

Even when trying the kotlin dsl version like [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/docs/manual/src/docs/asciidoc/_includes/servlet/oauth2/oauth2-resourceserver.adoc#using-decoder) by changing my configure function like bellow :

```kotlin
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http {
            authorizeRequests {
                authorize(anyRequest, authenticated)
            }
            oauth2ResourceServer {
                jwt {
                    jwtDecoder = jwtDecoder()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

it gives me the following errors :
[image]
The first line's this : `: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:  public operator fun <T, R> DeepRecursiveFunction<TypeVariable(T), TypeVariable(R)>.invoke(value: TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(R) defined in kotlin`

Running `gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency org.springframework.security:spring-security-config - -configuration runtimeClasspath` gives me this :

```
Welcome to Gradle 7.0!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - File system watching enabled by default
 - Support for running with and building Java 16 projects
 - Native support for Apple Silicon processors
 - Dependency catalog feature preview

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 2 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Evaluating settings

> Task :dependencyInsight
org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.4.6 (selected by rule)
   variant "runtime" [
      org.gradle.status                  = release (not requested)
      org.gradle.usage                   = java-runtime
      org.gradle.libraryelements         = jar
      org.gradle.category                = library

      Requested attributes not found in the selected variant:
         org.gradle.dependency.bundling     = external
         org.gradle.jvm.environment         = standard-jvm
         org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type = jvm
         org.gradle.jvm.version             = 8
   ]

org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:5.4.6
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:2.4.5
|    \--- runtimeClasspath
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.4.5
     \--- runtimeClasspath

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 21s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: A good starting point is to make sure you are using the version of Spring Security that you are expecting. Try running `./gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency org.springframework.security:spring-security-config --configuration runtimeClasspath` to see if another dependency is overriding it.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana I've run the command and edited my question with the result, it seems like there is only one version of `spring-security-config` which is 5.4.6

Comment: Try using the equivalent non-lambda configuration `oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().decoder(jwtDecoder())` to see if it changes anything. I also noticed that you are using Gradle 7. The Spring team uses Gradle 6 and there may be some features that are incompatible with Gradle 7. Try using Gradle 6.8.3 and see if it helps.

Comment: It seems like that works but now I'm having problems with the JUnit Test classes, I haven't modified them at all, it just seems like it can't find the annotations, should I add dependencies to them in my gradle build ? I didn't have any problems running my project before adding the security config and dependencies. Also changed my gradle version and it seems fine even when I didn't change it.

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment, mistake of mine from when I updated the spring boot version and forgot to do the same with the test class. The project now builds and runs without any errors. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the lambda version solved the issue as user [Eleftheria Stein-Kousathana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11430047/eleftheria-stein-kousathana) suggested :

`oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().decoder(jwtDecoder())`