# java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)

Tags: java, encryption, jwt, rsa, wso2-api-manager

I need to decode a token generated by wso2am. In the code, accessToken is the generated token, while publicKey is the string obtained by showing the contents of the wso2carbon.jks file at the path wso2carbon/wso2am-3.2.0/repository/resources/security.

```
    String publicKey = "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";
    String accessToken = "eyJ4NXQiOiJNell4TW1Ga09HWXdNV0kwWldObU5EY3hOR1l3WW1NNFpUQTNNV0kyTkRBelpHUXpOR00wWkdSbE5qSmtPREZrWkRSaU9URmtNV0ZoTXpVMlpHVmxOZyIsImtpZCI6Ik16WXhNbUZrT0dZd01XSTBaV05tTkRjeE5HWXdZbU00WlRBM01XSTJOREF6WkdRek5HTTBaR1JsTmpKa09ERmtaRFJpT1RGa01XRmhNelUyWkdWbE5nX1JTMjU2IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbkBjYXJib24uc3VwZXIiLCJhdWQiOiJ6VVJZbHd5NUJKR24xNUx4SFJPWkpmRUtjcFlhIiwibmJmIjoxNjgxOTIxOTIxLCJhenAiOiJ6VVJZbHd5NUJKR24xNUx4SFJPWkpmRUtjcFlhIiwic2NvcGUiOiJhbV9hcHBsaWNhdGlvbl9zY29wZSBkZWZhdWx0IiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo5NDQzXC9vYXV0aDJcL3Rva2VuIiwiZXhwIjoxNjgxOTI1NTIxLCJpYXQiOjE2ODE5MjE5MjEsImp0aSI6ImU3MTIxYjRmLWQyNzYtNDA5Mi1hNzEzLWEyY2I2MzkxMjNiZiJ9.uEA21GcgWaIt0tM3RA3rF9zhPigzcgSsSiQPn5SHq1qZCTe9R_2va2NTXCCza6MiYq6uWiQpXvlUlWEIkJkrLgRRc9oKw1DsdMTa9S8tSw4birr7QPBLUtMLgHae6ITiP7fAPQftHWwM5az5Z9p4zS0KkqXRQat42KsRwKL_7Sfi0ffQyGaBMHYacjviXgjTjaWmqnbvwLQTBmAlxvFLK91WmxwS9KUoWx4AK60aA3WGnp1ci65HmwFVLtu2t-Aev94VzGGzniYoyT17FzqZ1HupN3fqsgVf3-69-vHAcehu4P41Azzo6KjnhlmuE9F9jYD2Sa_MP79cJDYJE8XxUw";

    byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey);
    String algorithm = "RSA";
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
    PublicKey generatedPublic = kf.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(decoded));

    String[] chunks = accessToken.split("\\.");

    Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();

    String header = new String(decoder.decode(chunks[0]));
    String payload = new String(decoder.decode(chunks[1]));
    String signature = chunks[2];

    SignatureAlgorithm sa = SignatureAlgorithm.RS256;
    String tokenWithoutSignature = chunks[0] + "." + chunks[1];

    DefaultJwtSignatureValidator validator = new DefaultJwtSignatureValidator(sa, generatedPublic);

    if (!validator.isValid(tokenWithoutSignature, signature)) {
        System.out.println("=============== Invalid access token");
    } else {
        System.out.println("============= valid access token");
    }
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:240)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)
at it.egeos.aware.dm.orchestrator.testMain.main(testMain.java:22)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)
at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:397)
at sun.security.x509.X509Key.decode(X509Key.java:402)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:122)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:331)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:236)
... 2 more
```

How could I solve it?

Comment: No idea what is in *wso2carbon.jks*, but maybe no X.509/SPKI key. Check if your key is an X.509/SPKI key, e.g. with https://lapo.it/asn1js/ or post a sample key (preferably additionally an example for the token).

Comment: I posted the publicKey and token in full. The key seems valid. @Topaco

Comment: `MIIDq...` is a certificate. Load the certificate, extract the public key, s. e.g. [Obtaining public key from certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6358555/9014097).